# Confused about async validation in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Say I have a username field on my form and I want to validate it using async validation by making a server side `[Invoke]` call. Consider I have 2-3 more field in the forms and then I have a submit method which will basically add the user in the database if all goes well. Now because the validation is async, user can still input other fields and what if the call to the server was not completed and before the response is returned the client completes filling the form and hits the submit button? I am bound to get an error.

How do I handle these types of error? Should I disable Submit button? If yes, then how? because I am hooking up the Async call logic in the RIA extension methods i.e in partial class on the client like:

```
public void OnUsernameChanging()
{
    //make service call and handle it..
}
```

This method is in Entity class and not in code behind. Thus I cannot get a reference to submit button on Page and disable it. How do I handle it? One option is as I am using MVVM pattern, I always have Messenger class to the rescue and through it I can disable it. Are there any other options if the Messenger class was not available?

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented a similar solution I went by the old device;

> Its nice with client side validation, but server side validation is the one that matters.

IE async client side validation is used for display purposes, the real validation should either be in entity metaclasses or if more specific in the relevant `[update]` and `[insert]` methods of the service. Simple example below:

```
    if (!IsValidExampleEntity(entityToAddOrUpdate)) {
      var result = new ValidationResult(
         "A nice message", 
         new string[]{"the", "entity", "properties", "in", "error","as", "ienumerable<string>"});
      throw new ValidationException(result, null, entityToAddOrUpdate);
    } else {
      // Store it or whatnot...
    }
```

Do not prevent the user from doing a submiy, but put up a busyindicator or something else when submitting.